# iPhone memory leak and release problem on sorted array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, arrays, memory-leaks

I'm having some troubles with the code below:

```
NSSortDescriptor *idDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:ascending] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:idDescriptor];
NSArray *orderArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];  
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:orderArray];
```

If I use this code, Instruments says I have a memory leak, why?

Using this code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *idDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:ascending] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:idDescriptor];
NSArray *orderArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:orderArray];
```

I receive the leak warning too, however, if I autorelease the object result, a memory error happens.

Comment: Your second code block is allocating an NSMutableArray, you must send it a release message or it leaks.  Read this and see if it clears up some confusion (http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?AutoRelease)

Comment: As I said, if I send a release message I receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I'm using this code in an accessory function which is called everywhere to order an array using an specific key.

Comment: So, if I use this function:

- (NSMutableArray *) orderArray:(NSMutableArray *)array ByKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending {
 NSSortDescriptor *idDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:ascending] autorelease];
 NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:idDescriptor];
 NSArray *orderArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
 
 NSMutableArray *result = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:orderArray] autorelease];
 
 return result;
}

Have I to retain the object when it is received in any other piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better answer I think.

```
- (NSMutableArray *) orderArray:(NSMutableArray *)array ByKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending 
{ 
    NSSortDescriptor *idDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:ascending]];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:idDescriptor]; 
    NSArray *orderArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; 
    NSMutableArray *result = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:orderArray]];

    [release idDescriptor]; 
    return [result autorelease]; 
}
```

So, you allocate `idDescriptor`, then you use it, finally release it.  Since you're returning `result`, you can autorelease it with the return.  I have one more question though. Do you reference `result` elsewhere in your code?